# Запятая перед "и"

Tags: пунктуация

Не пойму, нужна тут запятая перед И или нет: "Поэтому представителям этого типа удобнее формировать свои личные отношения в рамках группы единомышленников, где все окружающие разделяют его взгляды(,) и он может быть более уверен в преданности своих друзей".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая не нужна. Это сложноподчиненное предложение с однородными придаточными, соединенными союзом И. В группе какой? - где все окружающие разделяют его взгляды - и в группе какой? - где он может быть уверен... Второе союзное  слово опущено.